# Nullpointer Exception is displayed when @FindBy is used with Static WebElement

Tags: selenium, findby

```
NullPointer Exception is displayed when static webelement is used with @FindBy  

Using driver.findElement.By.id("usr"),
```

Im able to locate element and sendkeys
    But usernameTB.sendKeys(username) is throwing Null Pointer Exception

```
public class LoginPage extends TestBase {

    // Page Factory or Object Repository
    @FindBy(id = "usr")
        static WebElement  usernameTB;
public LoginPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
public    static void loginFunction(String env, String username, String password) {


        try
        {

        if (env != null && username!=null && password!=null) {
            if (env.equals("dev")) {
                driver.findElement(By.id("usr")).sendKeys(username);                
                usernameTB.sendKeys(username);}}   catch(Exception e)
     {
      e.printstacktrace();
     }}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java and Selenium: Static methods in Page Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042096/java-and-selenium-static-methods-in-page-objects)

Comment: Thank you for the link...Any idea how to overcome this problem

Comment: Using static function and at the same time initializing page factory elements

Comment: Yes. Don't use PageFactory for static elements/functions.