# NullPointerException when using pagefactory

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

Code:

BASECLASS.JAVA

```
public class baseclass {
       public static WebDriver driver;
    public baseclass(WebDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub   
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public homepage intializedriver() throws IOException {

        Properties pr=new Properties();
        FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse - 
        workspace\\learning\\src\\main\\java\\baselearning\\config.properties");
        pr.load(fs);
        String browsername=pr.getProperty("browser");
        if(browsername.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(browsername.equals("firefox")) {
            //firefox code
        }
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, homepage.class);
    }

}
```

HOMEPAGE.JAVA

```
public class homepage extends baseclass {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public homepage(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
        super(driver);
    }


      @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Login & Signup')]")  
      public WebElement clickLogin;

      @FindBy(xpath="//button[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']") 
      public WebElement buttonclose;

      public void clicklogin() {
           clickLogin.click();

          }
      public void buttonclose() { 
          buttonclose.click();

}
```

TESTCLASS.JAVA

```
public class firstTest {

        public WebDriver driver;
        baseclass bs=null;
        homepage hp=null;

        @Test
        public void homepagenaviagation() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            bs=new baseclass(driver);
            bs.intializedriver();

            hp=new homepage(driver);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            hp.buttonclose();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            hp.clicklogin();
    }

}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.click(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

Let's start with `baseclass`. The Java convention is to start class names with an uppercase letter, so change the name to `BaseClass`.

```
public class BaseClass {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public BaseClass(WebDriver driver) { 
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```

The line `PageFactory.initElements` is ok, only if this class is inherited by others. You don't want to explictly create an instance of this class, so let's make it abstract.

Additionally, creating a `static` WebDriver will cause you a lot of problems in the future. Check out my answer on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042096/java-and-selenium-static-methods-in-page-objects/56042221#56042221) question where I explain why.

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public BaseClass(WebDriver driver) { 
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```

With the `BaseClass` like this, we just need to use `inheritance` on Page Object classes for them to be initialized.

The method `initalizedriver` should be renamed to `initializeDriver` to keep up with the Java naming convention. Camel case is used for method names `somethingLikeThis`.

```
    public homepage intializeDriver() throws IOException {
        Properties pr=new Properties();
        FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse - 
        workspace\\learning\\src\\main\\java\\baselearning\\config.properties");
        pr.load(fs);
        String browsername=pr.getProperty("browser");

        if(browsername.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        } else if(browsername.equals("firefox")) {
            //firefox code
        }

        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
    }
```

The method above returns `homepage` class which should also be renamed to `HomePage`.

```
public class homepage extends baseclass {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public homepage(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
        super(driver);
    }


      @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Login & Signup')]")  
      public WebElement clickLogin;

      @FindBy(xpath="//button[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']") 
      public WebElement buttonclose;

      public void clicklogin() {
           clickLogin.click();

          }
      public void buttonclose() { 
          buttonclose.click();

}
```

Let's fix the `homepage` class. Change its name. Remove the `public WebDriver driver` because you don't need it anymore. `HomePage` class extends `BaseClass` which already contains `protected WebDriver driver` to which you have access to because of the inheritance.

```
public class HomePage extends BaseClass {

    public homepage(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
        super(driver);
    }


      @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Login & Signup')]")  
      public WebElement clickLogin;

      @FindBy(xpath="//button[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']") 
      public WebElement buttonclose;

      public void clicklogin() {
           clickLogin.click();
      }

      public void buttonclose() { 
          buttonclose.click();

}
```

Let's get back for a moment to `initializeDriver()` method from `BaseClass`. The problem here is, that you return `HomePage` class with the last line of that method:

```
return PageFactory.initElements(driver, homepage.class);
```

This line will cause multiple problems but you need a deeper knowledge of Object-Oriented programming to fully understand the issue. To `quick fix` it, just change the method declaration to `static` like this:

```
public static HomePage intializedriver() throws IOException {
```

Now, the test class.

```
public class firstTest {

        public WebDriver driver;
        baseclass bs=null;
        homepage hp=null;

        @Test
        public void homepagenaviagation() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            bs=new baseclass(driver);
            bs.intializedriver();

            hp=new homepage(driver);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            hp.buttonclose();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            hp.clicklogin();
    }

}
```

Change the name, as I mentioned before.
Next thing is to utilize `@Before` annotation (JUnit) to initialize WebDriver, since it's not the part of the test. It's a prerequisite.

Then, we can either use `HomePage` class which is returned by `initializeDriver()` method, or initialize it in test class. Like this:

```
public class FirstTest {
        HomePage hp =null;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            hp = HomePage.initializeDriver(); //static method invocation
        }

        @Test
        public void homepagenaviagation() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            hp.buttonclose();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            hp.clicklogin();
    }

}
```

That's it!

I hope it helps!